# Why am I receiving 'Access to XMLHttpRequest' error on Chrome but not on Firefox in my React ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I have a react application and asp.net core web api. my react application is working fine in firefox browser but not working in chrome. In chrome, I got the following error in console

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I'm using Net Core 6.0. This is my program.cs code

```
string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "ReactPolicy";



// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MexDb");
var visaconnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("VisaDb");

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
    builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true);
                     
    });
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MexDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<VisaDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(visaconnectionString));
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                 ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```